# Is it possible to feed the response data of jmeter to a REST API?

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter to perform load testing of a REST API. I want to feed the response data of this test(which includes duration, size of the response) to another REST API.

Is there any way to do so using the tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter's [.jtl result files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) are basically CSV files having header and metrics for each and every [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)

[image]

So you can read this data using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and feed to whatever consumer you want.

If you want to choose which values, where and how to store you can consider going for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) plugin